# ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.Adam object at 0x7f149b4f7908>

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

my TensorFlow.keras is on '2.1.6-tf'`.

I have built a simple cnn as follows: but the optimizer isn't working, throwing this error  :

```
ValueError: Could not interpret optimizer identifier: <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers.Adam object at 0x7f149b4f7908>
```

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import datasets, layers, models, Input
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.regularizers import l2
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

# Compile model
opt = Adam(lr=0.0001, clipnorm=1.0, clipvalue=0.5)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer= opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu9KJ.png
```

Comment: 2.1.6-tf? are you sure?

Comment: yes ! i'm on that version ! I re-checked it

Comment: Are you mixing `keras` and `tf.keras`? That won't work. Please add the full code including _all_ used imports (`Sequential`, `Dense`) etc.

Comment: I tried `pip install tensorflow==2.1.6-tf` but no such version!

Comment: sorry, i provided the import `tensorflow.keras as tf`
>>tf.__version__ : '2.1.6-tf'     https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu9KJ.png

Comment: @xdurch0 I have added the imports in the code

Comment: Well as your code shows, you are indeed mixing `keras` and `tf.keras` which doesn't work. Change all `keras` imports to `tensorflow.keras` (e.g. `from tensorflow.keras import Sequential`) and it should work fine.

Comment: @xdurch0 thank you very much :') so sorry it was so stupid from me ! I mixed keras and tf.keras, it worked fine now.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import 'Adam' optimizer from keras using adam_v2:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import adam_v2
```

and then define your optimizer as below and small reminder `lr` keyword is deprecated you will use `learning_rate`:

```py
opt = adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipnorm=1.0, clipvalue=0.5)
```

then you can proceed...